# Failed to find conversion function from unknown to boolean error

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

```
query = """UPDATE table SET last_tracked = %s, being_tracked = %s WHERE(
                SELECT 'X' FROM temp_table
                WHERE table.selected_id = temp_table.selected_id);"""
cur.execute(query, [datetime.utcnow().isoformat(' ').split('.')[0] + ' z', True])
```

The above python/psycopg2 code gives the following error:

```
ERROR:  failed to find conversion function from unknown to boolean
STATEMENT:  UPDATE table 
            SET last_tracked = '2015-07-02 20:32:00 z', being_tracked = true 
            WHERE(
                SELECT 'X' FROM temp_table
                WHERE table.selected_id = temp_table.selected_id);
```

The following code works perfectly fine:

```
query = """UPDATE table SET being_tracked = %s
              WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                  SELECT 'X' FROM temp_table
                  WHERE table.selected_id = temp_table.selected_id);"""
cur.execute(query, [False])
```

I'm trying to only update rows that already exist in the table. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which is the type of the attribute last_tracked?

Comment: timestamp with time zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You´re missing the EXISTS in the WHERE predicate:

query = """UPDATE table SET last_tracked = %s, being_tracked = %s WHERE(
                SELECT 'X' FROM temp_table
                WHERE table.selected_id = temp_table.selected_id);"""

Should be:

query = """UPDATE table SET last_tracked = %s, being_tracked = %s WHERE EXISTS(
                SELECT 'X' FROM temp_table
                WHERE table.selected_id = temp_table.selected_id);"""

Dont?

Comment: oops! I'm very new to SQL and didn't know you had to put EXISTS there. Problem solved.